# Handle multiple data/parameters that change in Ajax - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

i am trying to filter custom post type called podcasts with ajax, using two custom taxonomies id as parameters, genre and country.

This is the front end: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYQDf.jpg.

As you can see, i can choose a genre or/and a country to use as filter for my posts (below there is an array with the parameters that are passed).

In my podcast page i have two foreach, with link within, with name and the term_id.

```
foreach ($genre/$country as $category) {
    echo '<a class="button-prova/button-prova2 premuto2"
    name="keyword/keyword2" id="keyword/keyword2" 
     value="'.$category->term_id.'" 
     href="#">'.$category->name.'</a>';   
}
```

Then, within function.php, i have my ajax function and ajax-fetch.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click touchend", ".premuto, .premuto2", function () {
    fetch(this);
    });
});
function fetch(prova){
    if($(prova).attr('name') == 'keyword'){
        var1 = $(prova).attr('value') ? jQuery(prova).attr('value') : 0;
    } else
          {
             var2 = $(prova).attr('value') ? jQuery(prova).attr('value') : 0;
          }
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: [var1,var2] },
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
        }
    });
}
```

At first, when i choose one genre, the country is set to 0, as you see in the code. But when i select the other taxonomy, genre set to 0 (or vice versa, like in the image). There is a way to store my precendent selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use AJAX. The previously selected value will persist if you declare the variable outside the functions. Try this.

```
var keywords = {};//Put this line outside of the function, so it available globally
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.premuto, .premuto2').on("click", function () {
        keywords[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).attr('value');
        fetch();
    });
});

function fetch(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: { 'action': 'data_fetch', 'keywords': keywords },
        success: function(data) {            
        }
    });
}
```

The keywords variable will look like this:

```
{keyword:0,keyword2:4}
```

And it will be read as an associative array in the PHP side.

Additional note: 
Using javascript global variables can lead to clashing variable names from other scripts/plugins. To remedy this, you can encapsulate all your scripts inside a self-invoked function like this:

```
(function(){ 
    /*PUT YOUR PLUGIN SCRIPTS HERE*/ 
})();
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I found a solution but this is easier. One question: using global variable is safe?

Comment: The caveat for using a global variable is that same variable name might be used for other scripts and plugins. To encapsulate it, you can wrap it in a self invoked function like this: `(function(){ /*PUT YOUR PLUGIN SCRIPTS HERE*/ })();`

Answer (score 0):

The buttons you use to filter have a certain markup (probably a class) when clicked. You can use that class as a toggle. In your 'fetch' function you can do:

```
keywords = Array();
$('.filters.toggle').each(function(){ // all filters with the toggle class
    // add those values to the keywords array
    keywords.push($(this).val()); // .val() is the same as attr('value')
});
```

keywords will be an array of all genres, countries that are toggled on.

then:

```
data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: keywords},
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not using a toggle class, but this event 'on("click touchend", ".premuto, .premuto2", function ()' because i can choose only one element for tax: for example jazz and italy, denmark and electronic

Comment: In that case you can a "toggle" class at the beginning of the click-event: $(this).toggleClass('toggle');

Comment: Instead of using toggle, i used addClass with this and removeClass for the siblings, so i can have only one button/link with the specific markup. Then my keyboards is an object with genre and country and two different each for the two list. Now it works. Thank you for your intuition